# CriteriaBuilder left join unrelated entities

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

This is my database schema:

- The `title` and `content` columns have a 1 to 1 relationship with the `translations_keys`
- There are many `translations_values` for each `translations_keys`

[image: Database Schema]

I'm trying to read posts with related fields translated according to the requested language. This the working query written in JPQL

```
@Query(value = """
    SELECT i AS template,
           tv_n.value AS title,
           tv_d.value AS content
      FROM Post i
 LEFT JOIN TranslationValue tv_n
        ON tv_n.key = i.title
       AND tv_n.languageIdentifier = ?1
 LEFT JOIN TranslationValue tv_d
        ON tv_d.key = i.content
       AND tv_d.languageIdentifier = ?1
""")
public Page<PostView> findAll(int languageIdentifier);
```

I need to rewrite this query using the CriteriaBuilder. This is what I tried but it doesn't work...

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PostView> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PostView.class);
Root<Post> root = query.from(Post.class);

Root<TranslationValue> translation = query.from(TranslationValue.class);
root.join("title", JoinType.LEFT).on(
    criteriaBuilder.equal(translation.get("key"), root.get("title")),
    criteriaBuilder.equal(translation.get("languageIdentifier"), 3)
);
root.join("title", JoinType.LEFT).on(
    criteriaBuilder.equal(translation.get("key"), root.get("content")),
    criteriaBuilder.equal(translation.get("languageIdentifier"), 3)
);
```

The problem is that the post entity has no direct relationship with the TranslationValue entity so I don't know how to perform the left join

This is my mapped Post entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(title = "posts")
@NamedQuery(title = "Post.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Post i")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(title = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer identifier;

    @Column(title = "title", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer titleIdentifier;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(title = "title")
    public TranslationKey title;

    @Column(title = "content", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer contentIdentifier;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(title = "content")
    private TranslationKey content;

    // Getter & Setter

}
```

Comment: Criteria API do not support that: https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence/issues/128